# How to generate a new node when another one hits a certain y value

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a circle moving up a line, and when that circle reaches a certain y point, how can I make it so that another node would generate from below?

Here is the code I currently have for populating the circles, but I am not able to use it with a physics body, as it generates too many nodes and slows down my app:

```
   func createCirclesOnLine(line: CGFloat) {
    var currentY : CGFloat = -110
    let maxY = self.size.width * 15
    let spacing : CGFloat = 120
    while currentY < maxY {
                        let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "first@2x")

            circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

            circle.position = CGPointMake(line,  currentY)


            //circle.physicsBody?.restitution = -900
            circle.size = CGSizeMake(75, 75)
                  // circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: circle.size)
                    let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 9000, duration: 90)


    circle.runAction(up)

           foregroundNode.addChild(circle)
        currentY += CGFloat((random() % 400) + 70)


    }
```

Will post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this.  One is to simply check every circle's y position to see if it's above the screen.  You'll need a reference to the circles so...

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    var circles = Array<SKSpriteNode>()
    ...
```

In your `createCirlcesOnLine` function, add each circle to the array as you create it.

```
...
self.addChild(circle)
circles.append(circle)
```

Then, in your update method, enumerate through the circles to see if any of them are above the top of the screen.

```
override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
    for circle in circles {
        if circle.position.y > self.size.height + circle.size.height/2 {
            //Send circle back to the bottom using the circle's position property
        }
    }
}
```

This solution will work but causes a lot of unnecessary checks on every update cycle.

A second more efficient (and slightly more complicated) recommendation is to add an invisible node above the top of the screen that stretches the screen width.  When the circle collides with it, just move it to the bottom of the screen.  Look into implementing the SKPhysicsContactDelegate protocol and what needs to happen for that to work.  If you run into problems with this solution, post a separate question with those issues.

Comment: It works great, but the physics body is still  slowing it down :(

Comment: How many circles do you have at this point counting the ones that aren't on the screen?  Performance in the simulator is going to be very different than performance on a device, especially if you have an older machine.

Comment: I have three circles but when I used your formula, they multiplied (obviously). If I ran it on a device would it work ok? My Mac was purchased in july of this year.

Comment: Just modify the formula to not create so many circles.  I just provided that as an example based on the picture you posted a few days ago.  Your maxY of `self.size.width * 15` is a bit of overkill.  Just modify it to only create the number of circles you need on the screen at a time.

Comment: Okay. Works good, but for some reason the physics body is now weighing down the circles and pulling them all to the bottom.

Comment: You can change the gravity of the scene or set each circle's physics body to not be affected by gravity.  `physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98931/discussion-between-trent-sartain-and-rae-tucker).